# Attaching CGI python script to PyCharm debugger?

Tags: python, debugging, cgi, pycharm, cgihttpserver

I'm using Community Edition PyCharm 4.5.1 and I'm developing CGI python scripts. My needs are to start the debugger and attach the script (then break to the first breakpoint) once it is called by my HTTP client.

I don't know if I can, I hope. Everything works fine, from the Python server to the HTML/JavaScript code that calls my CGI script. Also, I'm perfectly able to debug a Python script I just start normally. But now the problem is that it is the HTTP server that starts the script, neither me (from command line) nor the debugger itself.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you just put into your script

```
import cgitb    
cgitb.enable()  
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
```

and it's being debugged by itself.

Comment: Not exactly. This will dump the context but what I want is to break in the code then jump line by line.

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the same problem as yours when i use pycharm on CentOS, but i found pycharm can attach to cgi script automaticly **on windows**, so i try to follow the source code of CGIRequestHandler, I found there is a difference in CGIRequestHandler.run_cgi() function,  it will use fork on linux, and subprocess on windows, so i guess may be these two different ways of creating child process leading to different result.   so i try the following code,  force it subprocess on linux, and it works!

```
    CGIHTTPRequestHandler.have_fork = 0
    httpd = HTTPServer(('', port), CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
```